# Error about nodejs, express, mongoose(The object has no function)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got some error in the code! Please help me

I want to make a register function to my site, But I got some trouble question:

The code powered by Express 4.X

In the model, My code is :
model/Account.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var crypto = require('crypto');


module.exports = function(config, mongoose, nodemailer){

    var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        email: {type: String, unique: true},
        password: {type: String},
        name: {
            first: {type: String},
            last: {type: String}
        },
        birthday: {
            day: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 31, require: false},
            month: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 12, require: false},
            year: {type: Number}
        },
        photourl: {type: String},
        blography: {type: String}
    });

    var Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

    var registerCallback = function(err){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        };
        return console.log('Account was created!');
    };

    var changePassword = function(accountId, newpassword){
        var shaSum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        shaSum.update(newpassword);
        var hashedPassword = shaSum.digest('hex');
        Account.update({_id: accountId}, {$set:{password: hashedPassword}}, {upsert: false},
                      function changePasswordCallback(err){
                      console.log('Change password for' + accountId);
                      }
                      );
    };

    var forgetPassword = function(email, resetPasswordUrl, callback){
        var user = Account.findOne({email: email}, function findOne(err, doc){
            if(err){
                callback(false);
            }else{
                var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', config.mail);
                resetPasswordUrl += '?account' + doc._id;
                smtpTransport.sendMail({
                    from: 'admin@rccoder.net',
                    to: doc.email,
                    subject: 'Password Request',
                    text: 'Click to get password' + reserPasswordUrl
                }, function fogotPasswordUrl(err){
                    if(err){
                        callback(false);
                    }else{
                        callback(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };

    var login = function(emai, password, callback){
        var shaSum = crypto.createHasn('sha256');
        shaSm.update(password);
        Account.findOne({email: email, password: shaSum.digest('hex')}, function(err, doc){
            callback(null != doc);
        });
    };

    var register = function(email, password, firstName, lastName){
        var shaSum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        shaSum.update(password);
        console.log('Register in ' + email);
        var user = new Account({
            email: email,
            name: {
                first: firstName,
                last: lastName
            },
            password: shaSum.digest('hex'),
        });
        user.save(registerCallback);
        console.log('Save command was send!');
    };

    return{
        register: register,
        forgotPassword: forgotPassword,
        changePassword: changePassword,
        login: login,
        Account: Account
    }
}
```

My router is this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Account = require('../models/Account.js')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
 res.render('login', {title: 'Login'});
});
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
 console.log('login Request:');
 var email = req.param('Email', null);
 var password = req.param('Password', null);
 if(null = email || email.length < 1 || null = password || password.length < 1){
  res.send(400);
  return;
 }
 Account.login(email, password, function(success){
  if(!success){
   res.send(401);
   return;
  }else{
   console.log('Login is success!');
   res.send(200);
  }
 });
});

router.get('/reg', function(req, res, next){
 res.render('reg', {title: 'Register'});
});
router.post('/reg', function(req, res, next){
 console.log('Reg Request:');
 var email = req.body['Email'];
 var password = req.body['Password'];
 var FirstName = req.body['FirstName'];
 var LastName = req.body['LastName'];
 if(null == email || null == password){
  res.send(400);
  return;
 }else{
  Account.register(email, password, FirstName, LastName);
  res.send(200);
 }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Ans the temple called reg.html is this:

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>
<form method="POST">
 <label for="Email">Email:</label>
 <input type="text" name="Email">
 <label for="Password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" name="Password">
 <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
 <input type="text" name="FirstName">
 <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
 <input type="text" name="LaseName">
 <input type="submit" value="Reg">
</form>
<ul>
 <li><a href="forgotPassword">ForgotPassword ?</a></li>
 <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

But if I checked the submit called REG in reg.html, There is some error:

```js
 Object function (config, mongoose, nodemailer){ var AccountsSchema = new ……………………）has no method 'register'
```

and the console is that:

```html
Reg Request:
POST /reg 500 25.466 ms - 7685
```

I don't konw waht is happened in my code!

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model the only thing you `export` is a single function. 
To make this work you should call the function with its parameters `(config, mongoose, nodemailer)`. This will return an object wich contains references to functions you want to call. You're probably overlooking this because the error message is quite clear.

Besides that, I would suggest to rewrite things a bit. You probably want to remove this line altogether:

```
module.exports = function(config, mongoose, nodemailer){
```

and just export the functions:

```
module.exports = {
    register: register,
    forgotPassword: forgotPassword,
    changePassword: changePassword,
    login: login,
    Account: Account
}
```

go from there

Comment: Oh! Yes. I change the code with `var Account = require('../models/Account.js')(config, mongoose, nodemailer);`, But there is another problem ,the console told me `  var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Schema' of undefined
    
`

Comment: that's probably because `mongoose` in `var Account = require('../models/Account.js')(config, mongoose, nodemailer)` is `undefined`. Again, the error message is clear. But I suggest to rewrite the design a bit: it is bad. You shouldn't pass the kitchen sink with every function call. For example, in the case of `mongoose`, you should `require` it in every module where it is needed, and not pass it as a parameter. You could find some examples from there github repo I presume. After that, I would do the stuff I wrote above